# Joining two files based on two key columns awk

Tags: text-processing, awk, join

I've been trying to merge two big files based on two key columns (Chromosome and Position) and I found out that the most efficient way seems to be `awk`.

A sample of how my files look like is:

```
file1.txt
Gene_ID Chromosome Position Fst
ENSG00000141424 18 33688658 0
ENSG00000141424 18 33688669 0
ENSG00000141424 18 33688681 0
ENSG00000141424 18 33688683 0.0111734
ENSG00000141424 18 33688720 0
ENSG00000141424 18 33688726 0
ENSG00000141424 18 33688743 0
ENSG00000141424 18 33688745 0
ENSG00000141424 18 33688763 0
```

And the other file:

```
file2.txt
Chromosome Start End Ref Alt RS_ID
1   10019   10020   TA  T   rs775809821
1   10020   10020   A   -   rs775809821
1   10055   10055   -   A   rs768019142
1   10055   10055   T   TA  rs768019142
1   10108   10108   C   T   rs62651026
1   10109   10109   A   T   rs376007522
1   10128   10128   A   AC  rs796688738
1   10128   10128   -   C   rs796688738
1   10139   10139   A   T   rs368469931
1   10144   10145   TA  T   rs144773400
```

I want to get a third file looking like this:

```
Gene_ID Chromosome Position RS_ID Fst
ENSG00000141424 18 33688658 rs1504554... 0
```

I've tried using `awk` and I think the syntax is OK but what I get is a file containing `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` concatenated.

```
awk  'FS=" "; OFS=" ";NR=FNR{A[$1,$2]=$6;next}{$5=A[$2,$3];print}' file1.txt file2.txt > file3.txt
```

Any ideas of what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few correction of your code should fix it

```
awk 'NR==FNR{A[$1,$2]=$6;next}{$5=A[$2,$3];if($5!="")print}' file2.txt file1.txt
```

- `NR==FNR` instead of `NR=FNR` is the condition when awk runs through the first file `file2.txt`
- On the second run when `NR!=FNR` we print out the line if there exists a join key in `A`
- The default field separator for awk is already a whitespace, so no need to specify them here

Comment: That solved the problem! Thank you so much!!